# Is it safe to flush the swap space?

Tags: ram, swap

I've noticed that my swap space has been at 410 MiB for the past three days. Is that normal, or should I flush it, and if so, how? I've got total 3.69 GiB Ram, and 1.33 GiB swap.

Comment: Thanks Raffa!!!

Comment: It's complete safe to erase your swap and ram for the swap use sswap to see manual use # man sswap . and if you want to secure erase the ram you sdmem to see full manual use # man sdmem

Comment: Okay thanks. I don't have manual for those. man swap, or man sdmem. However, there's man for mkswap, swapoff, swapon, etc. So I'll probally find a more detailed explanation there.

Comment: @Raffa re: "swap space is used for temporary system and application files". That's totally incorrect. swap is used to store least used active memory pages.

Comment: to be able to use sswap and sdmem you can install secure-delete package , # apt-get install secure-delete , it support many tool for secure erase .

Comment: @Raffa first half true, second half not. Swap has no idea, and doesn't care, about system and application **files**. It only cares about the "least used active memory pages".

Comment: @Raffa No. Crude example. You have an app that inits the video screen, and then displays patterns on the screen. The init code is only called once. The pattern drawing code runs continuously after that. Along comes another app that consumes more memory, and the system has to decide how to make room for the new app. It looks and finds that init code for the first app hasn't been used in a while, moves those memory **pages** of init code out to swap, and leaves it there unless it's needed again. No knowledge of **files** exists.

Comment: @Raffa the difference between moving **pages**, and **temp files**, to/from swap, is quite distinct. **Pages** is correct. **Files** is not. This is a fundamental difference, and if you continue to say/think **files**, I'll have to call you/anybody out on that definition and say you're wrong. Sorry. :-)

Comment: @Raffa another point... unused memory is used for **file** and **disk** buffers. The **file** buffers can contain files.

Answer (score 2):

Swap space is automatically filled or emptied as needed; you don't have to flush, purge, or erase it. Even if you don't use all your memory, Linux will go out and get what it thinks are the least used active memory pages and puts them in the Swap; that way, they're ready if needed.

The [swappiness parameter](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-swappiness/) can be tuned, if you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering K7AAY. I actually just changed the swappiness to 15 after finding out that it's default is 60. I've got very limited Ram and for some reason Firefox nearly consumes 600 MiB. Not sure if thats normal so ill be looking into that next.

Comment: K7AAY I don't think this is what swap is used for. Swap is used to store memory pages to prevent ram from filling up (which would result in a kernel panic). To use the swapped out pages, they have to be copied back to system memory, which is painfully slow compared to direct ram access. Therefore, the system stores pages that are very _un_likely to be used in the near future in swap. @Snwx browsers nowadays use ridiculous amounts of ram. 600MiB is not abnormal.

Comment: @danzel Please see https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-space/ which states in part _The Linux Kernel will move memory pages which are hardly ever used into swap space to ensure that even more cachable space is made available in-memory for more frequently used memory pages (a page is a piece of memory)._

Comment: @Snxw setting your vm.swappiness to 15 is totally wrong for 4G RAM and 1G swap.

Comment: @K7AAY re: "Linux will go out and get what it thinks are the most likely files to be needed and puts them in the Swap". That's totally incorrect. Linux does NOT move FILES to swap. It moves memory pages to swap.

Comment: @heynnema Corrected, and thank you.

Comment: @K7AAY minor nit... swap is used to store least used active memory pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to flush the swap, if you're using the following commands:

```
sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a
```

(`-a` stands for `--all` swap devices)

If there's enough space in RAM, `swapoff` will flush pages from swap to pages in memory. Else it will end on error, which will stop the second command.

You may need to flush the swap if the application you're using has pages in swap, which make it slower.

Else the kernel will handle this automatically, so most of the time, there's no need to do this.